# Application get crash on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

My application get crash on launch . It never goes on app didfinish

> 2015-10-09 15:41:55.396 MÖLLER[11840:574331]  Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x026cc746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x01f9ca97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x025c2c93 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
>   + 451     3   CoreFoundation                      0x025d6b7b +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 75    4   MOÃàLLER                            0x0004d65b -[TabBarViewController
>   viewDidLoad] + 3291   5   UIKit
>   0x00a97db7 -[UITabBarController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 221    6
>   MOÃàLLER                            0x0008984d -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 268     7   UIKit
>   0x008e5f87 -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 287  8   UIKit                               0x008e6d71 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2938   9   UIKit                               0x008ea3d2 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639   10  UIKit                               0x009038ee _84-[UIApplication
>   handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 59  11  UIKit                               0x008e8ffa -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155   12  FrontBoardServices                  0x03208c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace
>   clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71    13  FrontBoardServices
>   0x0320872f _40-[FBSWorkspace performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke +
>   54    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0321ad7c
>   __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30   15  CoreFoundation                      0x025ee050
>   CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 16  16  CoreFoundation
>   0x025e3963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195  17  CoreFoundation
>   0x025e37bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715  18  CoreFoundation
>   0x025e2a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x025e288b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   20  UIKit
>   0x008e89b2 -[UIApplication _run] + 571    21  UIKit
>   0x008ec0b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526   22  MOÃàLLER
>   0x0006a509 main + 94  23  libdyld.dylib
>   0x03fe1ac9 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: please mention your code or else bit more.

Comment: My code is working fine but when i clean and run project i got this issue

Comment: it would be great if you post the code that causes the crash!!!

Comment: OK solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue is resolved. As My Home View Have Ref of Font which we never used in app.

Answer (score 1):

the error says

`-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

The error means you are trying to put `nil` in the dictionary (which is not allowed). Since you are building the dictionaries with string literals those can't be `nil`.